# After inheriting class, can't keep my constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

We trying to inherit a class from another class , were expected to delete the constructor from the base class but we want to implement a method in the derived class that creates and returns an object from the base class

```
namespace IntroSE.Kanban.Backend.DataAccessLayer
{
  class Task
  {
    private int taskId;
    private string title;
    private string description;
    private DateTime creationDate;
    private DateTime dueDate;
    public Task(int taskId, string title, string description, DateTime dueDate)
    {
      this.taskId = taskId;
      this.title = title;
      this.description = description;
      this.creationDate = DateTime.Now;
      this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }
  }
}

namespace IntroSE.Kanban.Backend.BusinessLayer.BoardPackage
{
  class Task : DataAccessLayer.Task
  {
    private int taskId;
    private string title;
    private string description;
    private DateTime creationDate;
    private DateTime dueDate;
    public Task(int taskId, string title, string description, DateTime dueDate) //here we have the issue
    {
      this.taskId = taskId;
      this.title = title;
      this.description = description;
      this.creationDate = DateTime.Now;
      this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }
```

Comment: you should do:
 public Task(int taskId, string title, string description, DateTime dueDate) : this(params to base ctor)

Comment: Your classes look the same what is the meaning of the inheritance?

Comment: I'm not clear on the requirements or what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you allowed to edit the base class?  I'm not sure what you mean by "delete the constructor form the base class".

Comment: Why duplicate all the fields in the derived class? With protected instead of private you can access the base fields in the derived class

Comment: When the baseclass doesn't have a parameter less constructor, you need to explicitly call it from the derived class

Comment: Task that inherits Task?  That's confusing.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? You didn't show that method that you were trying to implement or the problems with implementing it

Comment: Are you sure inheritance is needed here?  As @HansKeﬆing requested, what extactly are you trying to do?

Comment: its the requirement to this exactly , well i sorted it out thank you all for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you get the error, you should use `public Task(int taskId, string title, string description, DateTime dueDate) : base(taskId, title, description, dueDate)`. This way the base class' constructor is called. This only solves your build error, I have no idea about your method because It is not given in the question.